# I am trying to publish web application as a deployment package and while publish i'm getting the below error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-deployment

I am trying to publish web application as using a deployment package and while publish I'm getting the below error. Tried with different ways to resolve like update the JSON reference and … etc.

DLL is available, but no luck

***Error :***

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Copying file packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1\lib\portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll to C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\xyzwebapplication-150487496\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1\lib\portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll failed. Could not find a part of the path 'packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1\lib\portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.  xyzwebapplication       0
```

Comment: Well, the publishing routine can't find the file. Are you sure you have that version of the Newtonsoft Json.Net NuGet package installed? You mention "the JSON reference", but it's not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !Yes i have installed nuget package with Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1 .I mean what "json" is Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1.Please see the complete error for more details

Comment: Stupid question: Is the assembly file actually located at the specified location? It looks like a relative path, so is it the same place where you think it's supposed to be?

Comment: Yes,assembly file is available in this location. packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1\lib\portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll   .WHile publish it is trying to copy to the temp folder.There the error occurs. Please see the complete error for more details.  Note:VS is running as Admin .But still the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Has been solved After I did remove the unwanted packages from the solution.

Remove packages and clean solution ,rebuild followed by publish.

> Project-->Packages-->remove

The folders like **"Json"** etc..

It was success